# Set the rotation of an object at its axis three js

Tags: object, rotation, three.js

I try to set the rotation of an object at it's own axis using:

```
object.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0) , Math.PI)
```

in the render function, but the object is rotating in every rendering. Is there a way to set the rotation at it's own axis like when using:

```
object.rotation.x = Math.PI
```

or

```
object.rotation.set(Math.PI,0,0)
```

to set the rotation at the world axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rotation must take place at the render function that means that the model is changing rotation at every render. Simply find the rotation difference and apply it to the model using the code mentioned:

```
object.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0) , Math.PI);
```

Store the old rotation and the new rotation at variables and apply the difference:

```
var old_rotation = value1;
var new_rotation = value2;
var Drotation = value1-value2;
```

if the difference is negative or positive it shows the direction of the rotation so just apply:

```
object.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0) , Drotation);
```

**UPDATE**:
 The simplest way i found is:

```
object.rotateX(angle);
object.rotateY(angle);
object.rotateZ(angle);
```

this rotates the object around its axes :D

Comment: there should be a much simplier way to let the object rotate. I edited my answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the following code from the `render` method.

```
object.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0) , Math.PI)
```

You could put it to the declaration of `object`. Surely, you could also set the rotation there (in `render`) but that would reduce the performance needlessly.

**Simply put it outside the render function.**

EDIT: You can simply use

```
object.rotation.x += rotationSpeed;
```

in the `render` method to let it rotate.

Comment: i need to change the rotation in every render because the model is moving at a terrain model with different elevation. i found a solution and i will post it :)

Comment: sry, i misunderstood the question. i edited my answer.

Comment: the problem with the object.rotation.x is that my model changes orientation. Imagine a car moving in the 3d space. if the car move parallel with the z axis and i make rotation.x ++ the car will rotate as if it goes on a hill. Now if the model move parallel with the x axis and i make rotation.x the model will rotate at the world axis x and not its own so the one one side(left or right ) of the car will rotate and not the front or the back as i want.